# Use SASS to dynamically add color stops to linear-gradient

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

Using SASS, I am trying to create a dynamic linear-gradient, so if I have an array of colors, I would like to loop through it and add each color to the gradient.

```
@import "compass";

$colors: red green blue;
$numColors: length($colors);

div {
  $g: nth($colors, 1);
  @for $h from 2 to ($numColors + 1) {
    $g: $g , nth($colors, $h);
  }
  border: $g;
  background: linear-gradient($g);
}
```

This results in the following error

```
At least two color stops are required for a linear-gradient
```

Removing the background parameter will compile, and looks like this

```
border: red, green, blue;
```

(I know that's not a valid border, I just wanted to "trace" out $g)

How can I dynamically iterate through an array and create a linear gradient?

Comment: Did you intend to use the compass `linear-gradient` mixin which adds vendor prefixes, or the standard CSS `linear-gradient`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 problems here.

1. linear-gradient is a custom Compass function, that's what's generating that error.  As such, it expects a specific number of arguments.
2. You're not creating a list with 3 elements in it, you're creating a list with a single element in it that looks something like this: `[[red, green], blue]`.  The first element of the list is a list containing 2 elements.

What you're needing here is the `append()` function:

```
div {
  $g: nth($colors, 1);
  @for $h from 2 to ($numColors + 1) {
    $g: append($g , nth($colors, $h));
  }
  border: $g;
  background: linear-gradient($g);
}
```

That will give you your expected output:

```
div {
  border: red green blue;
  background: linear-gradient(#ff0000, #008000, #0000ff);
}
```